# Keras LSTM model only predicts in one direction for a one step ahead prediction

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, prediction

I have an interesting problem with the predictions of my keras LSTM model. The goal of my model is to predict the changes in high and low prices for a selected FX rate pair based on the following variables: open, high, low, close and volume. My data frame looks as follows:

[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuRIz.png)

Before training my model, I applied the following data preparation steps to my data frame:

1. Calculated the percentage changes from one point in time to the next one (current - previous)/previous for all columns shown in the data frame above.
2. Applied zero-mean normalization for each column on all columns.
3. Used the MinMaxScaler to transform the data in each column between [-1,1].
4. As I wanted to train an LSTM model, I have also applied a lookback window to the data frame (see code below).

   `df_all_lookback_x = {}
   for i in range(0,window_size+1):
     if(i==0):
        df_all_lookback_x = df_x
     else:
       df_all_lookback_x = pd.concat([df_x.shift(i),df_all_lookback_x], axis=1)`

The model itself was then trained as shown below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='tanh'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

If I then use the model to predict on train + test data, both: the percentage changes for low and high prices do not make sense to me. It seems like for the predicted high percentage price changes nearly all values are to low (forming a line at the mean) and for the low percentage price changes it is the opposite. Please find the pictures below.

[Prediction vs Real](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz07V.png)

[Prediction vs Real](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyh9W.png)

Has anyone experienced a similar problem and would be able to advise me on this issue?

Things already tried out:

1. Used a different number of features as input for the model.
2. Changed model parameters: lookback window, epochs, dropout rate, LSTM model size
3. Changed input for model: removed normalization steps
4. Used different loss functions, optimizers
5. Tanh, linear, relu as activation functions
6. Tried to predict only one output variable instead of both, the high + low percentage price changes.